# Android : Create a table programatically with n columns and different column types : How to do?

Tags: android, uitableview, dynamic, view, runtime

I have an requirement to fulfill and I would like to ask, whether I am going into the right direction.

I will try to post the requirement as clear as possible:

### I need to create a table programatically during runtime.

1. The number of columns and headers (1 : 1)  are received during runtime.
2. The headers can be of any basic type like : Label, TextView, CheckBox, Button ( meaning, they do not necessary define the columns type ).
3. The headers are visible or not, received during runtime
4. The column itself also can be of the basic types like Label, TextView, CheckBox, Button ( but this stays, means, the column type of the first table row defines all following rows' column ).
5. The columns width will be received at runtime.
6. A vertical scrollbar can be visible or not, and their width will be received at runtime.
7. The amount of visible rows will be received at runtime.
8. The location and size of the table will be received at runtime ( embedded into a fragment's 
   AbsoluteLayout), but it is not resizable once it has been created.
9. Depending on the type of the column, an event handler ( consumer ) must be attached.... perhaps already possible...
10. The height and width of the headers also will be received during runtime
11. The rows height also will be received during runtime, all columns have he same height, and all the rows also. So one value for all rows.
12. A horzontal scroll shall be faked, meaning, setting a special amount of left columns to invisible and/or setting their size to 0, so that the following columns can "rearrange" and slide to the place, where the predecessors have been visible

---

Question:

Until now I have been reading about TableView in order to realize the requirement.
First I would like to know, whether the TableView is sufficient enough to realize the requirements.

Comment: you might jut want to make the table out of linear layout containing framelayouts as cells and then you can stuff it with whatever you want as long as you keep the framelayout´s weight of value 1, meaning the width and height would be the same for each column and/or row. how about that? then you can easily hide or show whatever you need...

Comment: I updated my question. The thing with height especially.
(No, the columns have different width, but all the same height, once defined. The headers height also is received during runtime.

Comment: I ended up in creating a custom compound control. Was no other way. Android development , as I realized, is best when You try to have the control whereever possible.